# Rails 4 validation :greater_than :less_than on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I have a Player model and table in my rails app.  There is a field highest_level (int) which stores the player's highest level achieved.  Due to multiple profiles per player, there are instances where the level reported could be less than the highestLevel in the database.

I did some research on validates and validates_numericality_of and it appears that I can use :greater_than or :less_than respectively for my needs.

in my Player model I tried this:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_numericality_of :highestLevel, greater_than: self.highestLevel
end
```

However, performing an update of a highest level value greater or lesser updates regardless:

```
Player.update(8, highestLevel: 12)
```

What I am expecting to get is no update since my value for player ID 8 has a highestLevel of 15.  Does anyone have an example they can post or point me to?

Much Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your `highestLevel` attribute of scoped record will not be evaluated as you have written the code.

You can use `Proc` to access the value of scoped record:

```
validates_numericality_of :highestLevel, greater_than: Proc.new { |r| r.highestLevel_was }
```

Comment: I gave your example a spin, but I'm getting the same thing as before - the highestLevel value updates regardless if it's greater or less than the stored value.  I'm running a rails 4.1.4 with Ruby 2.1. According to the docs, that shouldn't make a difference though.

Comment: have a look on updated answer, using `highestLevel_was`

Comment: I gave that a whirl too, but same result